# VBA code simplification

Tags: vba, excel

I have the following macro

```
Private Sub ComboBox1_Change()

    If ComboBox1 = "Berlin" Then

    Range("C20").Activate

Else
    If ComboBox1 = "Paris" Then

    Range("C100").Activate

Else
    If ComboBox1 = "London" Then

    Range("C150").Activate

End If
End If
End If

End Sub
```

This macro takes the value from a dropdown menu and goes to the cell, where the value is. First question is:

How can I take the values from the cells and not write them specifically in the code?

Second question is:

How can I simplify the procedure and not write for every value an IF?

Comment: `How can I take the values from the cells?`. Are you refering to "Berlin", "Paris", etc or to "C20", "C100" etc? Anyway, I guess it depends on your data structure. For example, if cells between C20 and C100 are all empty. I think you should provide more data. Maybe a snapshot of your table.

Comment: There are two separate questions here. @Wolfie 's answer solves your problem about not writing the cell values specifically in the code, and my answer addresses not writing an `If` for every condition you want to check. Wolfie's 3rd code block is a good solution to your situation and is probably the *main* answer that you want.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First, you probably don't actually want to `Activate` the range! See this answer:
[How to avoid using Select in Excel VBA macros](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10714251/how-to-avoid-using-select-in-excel-vba-macros)

Secondly, your code...

**Your Code**

```
Private Sub ComboBox1_Change()

If ComboBox1 = "Berlin" Then

    Range("C20").Activate

Else

    If ComboBox1 = "Paris" Then

       Range("C100").Activate
    Else

        If ComboBox1 = "London" Then

            Range("C150").Activate

        End If

    End If

End If

End Sub
```

**Using ElseIf**

```
Private Sub ComboBox1_Change()

If ComboBox1 = "Berlin" Then

    Range("C20").Activate

ElseIf ComboBox1 = "Paris" Then

    Range("C100").Activate

ElseIf ComboBox1 = "London" Then

    Range("C150").Activate

End If

End Sub
```

See documentation: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/gg251599.aspx

**Not hard-coding the values**

```
Private Sub ComboBox1_Change()

    Dim rng as Range
    Set rng = Nothing
    Set rng = ActiveSheet.Range("C:C").Find(ComboBox1.Text)

    If Not rng Is Nothing Then
        ' As I say, you probably don't actually want to use Activate!
        rng.Activate 

    End If 

End Sub
```

See more about the `Range` object here:

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff838238.aspx

It has useful methods like `Address` or `Value` for common use in VBA. The `Find` function returns a `Range` object or `Nothing` if the given value isn't found in the given range.

Answer (score 3):

> How can I simplify the procedure and not write for every value an IF?

If you need to test your ComboBox repeatedly (like your `If-ElseIf` structure), you can use the `SELECT CASE` to simplify your code:

```
Private Sub ComboBox1_Change()

Select Case ComboBox1
    Case Is = "Berlin"
        Range("C20").Activate
    Case Is = "Paris"
        Range("C100").Activate
    Case Is = "London"
        Range("C150").Activate
    Case Else
        Range("C1").Activate
End Select

End Sub
```

This looks at the value of ComboBox1 and picks the appropriate section to run. For example, if ComboBox1 = "Paris", it skips to the "Paris" case and only runs that section (`Range("C100").Activate`).

This makes it much easier to add more items to your options, and it reduces the clutter of lots of `If-ElseIf-Else` lines.

Edit: As mentioned by Wujaszkun, adding the `Case Else` section handles a ComboBox1 value that was not one of the specified cases.

Comment: I would also add `Case Else` before `End Select` to catch all other cases. It may not be needed but it's good to have.

Comment: @Wujaszkun Good point, I've edited the question to include it now. Thanks